How do I get XSSFWorkbook to throw a Dialog error instead of printing it on terminal?
Don't have a lot of experience with Java but I'm currently coding a very basic JavaFX app and trying to read information from an excel file. This is all working fine, however, the issue I'm having is when trying to handle errors by having it open an Alert Dialog instead of printing them onto the terminal window. I've currently got the code below but for whatever reason, nothing happens on the UI and I get the errors below printed instead. Any help would be appreciated.#
protected void uploadNames() {
        try {
            FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);

            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            for (int i = 0; i < spreadsheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
                TextField textField = new TextField(spreadsheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).toString());
                textField.setEditable(false);
                namesList.getChildren().add(textField);
                arrayNamesList.add(textField);
                textField.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                        namesList.getChildren().remove(textField);
                        arrayNamesList.remove(textField);
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Alert.AlertType alertType = Alert.AlertType.ERROR;
            Alert alert = new Alert(alertType, "Error");
            alert.getDialogPane().setContentText("Just checking this box open when error is found");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }

ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: Element presentation@http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main is not a valid workbook@http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main document or a valid substitution.
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml/org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:479)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml/org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:169)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml/org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:260)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml/org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:313)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml/org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:287)
        at com.projects.firsttry@1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.projects.firsttry.ApplicationController.uploadNames(ApplicationController.java:89)
        at com.projects.firsttry@1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.projects.firsttry.ApplicationController$3.handle(ApplicationController.java:142)
        at com.projects.firsttry@1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.projects.firsttry.ApplicationController$3.handle(ApplicationController.java:139)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3984)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1890)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2708)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: Element presentation@http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main is not a valid workbook@http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main document or a valid substitution.
        at org.apache.xmlbeans/org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.autoTypeDocument(Locale.java:229)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans/org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.lambda$parseToXmlObject$3(Locale.java:719)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans/org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.syncWrap(Locale.java:491)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans/org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:717)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans/org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:234)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans/org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.AbstractDocumentFactory.parse(AbstractDocumentFactory.java:71)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml/org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:395)
        ... 38 more

I have also tried having the method with throws exception and tried doing try and catch when the method is called but this produced the same result.

it looks like you need to add the Log4j2 dependency.

@SedJ601, just done this, however, whilst it's removed the below line from the terminal error, the rest is the same "ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console..."

It's also saying that the Workbook is not valid.

Going back to your original question, if you want the alert to show, try catching XmlException.

The exception in the stack trace is a POIXMLException, but you are catching IOException. The former is not a subtype of the latter. And the former is an unchecked exception, which means the compiler does not force you to handle it. In other words, you are not catching the POIXMLException, and so your show-alert code is not being executed.
If you want to handle either IOException or POIXMLException then you can add the latter to your catch:
try {
  ...
} catch (IOException | POIXMLException e) {
  ...
}

Note this will stop the exception from propagating. Since your catch block does not log the exception there will be no stack trace in the console/logs. While alerting the user that something went wrong is good, I recommend you still log the exception. That way you can see what went wrong and where.

Thank you, that's worked and yah, also planning on using some other way to log the errors but just wanted to first get the user side of it working

To me, this is a perfect situation to use Exception Dialog. That way, users can copy the text and email it to the developer. Example here under Exception Dialog.

Also, the OP can probably reduce the chance that this happens by making the FileChooser only accept files with the appropriate file extension.
